# Is Alice Kingsleigh not able to return for a Wonderland visit ever again?

Tags: plot-explanation, through-the-looking-glass

> **Time:** [Alice has given Time her father's fob watch] It is said that time is
>   no man's friend, but I will remember you. Please don't come back.

Is Time actually being sarcastic to remind Alice not to repeat her terrible mistake:

> Stole the Chronosphere and caused chaos in Wonderland. But the one actually ruined the past and caused doomsday in the ending was The Red Queen, wasn't it?

or simply wishes Alice not to come back ever again? If that's so, is Alice not allowed to visit Wonderland whenever she wants to? Is it because her mission in Wonderland was accomplished, just like the plot of Narnia movie?

Comment: Is this about the "Through the Looking Glass" movie? I've added its tag. If I'm incorrect, please remove it and add the tag for the movie you are referring to. Thanks, and welcome to M&TV!

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Yes indeed. Sure appreciate your help :)